# Check against every unique pair of objects in an NSArray

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, macos, ipad

I have an array of numbers. I need to compare every number in the array with every other number in the array without any duplication of comparison sets. Example, need to compare objects at index 0 and 1 but don't want to double up later by checking objects at index 1 and 0.

Can anyone help me out with the algorithm for this. It would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you say why, you might even get a better solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what you need to do this for as there are probably better ways to accomplish whatever you are trying to do, but for the case you are talking about, you could do a simple:

```
for (int n=0;n<[array count];n++) {
    for (int m=n+1;m<[array count];m++) {
        //check your array based on objects at index n and m;
    }
}
```

This just loops through the array from beginning to end, and for each object loops through every object after it and you can compare them or do whatever. Starting the inner loop at `n+1` instead of `0` prevents you from repeating comparisons.

Comment: This is essentially the way I'd do it, unless I had to figure out something better for performance reasons.  (Though note that the first loop can stop one iteration sooner than where you do.)  You can, of course, instead have the second loop index up through n-1, starting the first loop at 1.

Comment: The first loop could go one less and I almost added a `-1`, but for simplicity sake, there is almost no performance loss in doing this as in the last iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop will be exited immediately.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that the difference is negligible, in most cases.

Answer (score 2):

Use an NSMutableOrderedSet if it helps solve your problem. Or another mutable array and add objects from your original array to it one by one using `containsObject:` to test if the object youre about to insert will be a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array and at each number compare it with the next numbers in the array only.
if you have array with size 5, then at arr[2] compare it with arr[3], arr[4] only.

psudo code:

```
NSArray *arr;
for(int i = 0; i < arr.count ; i++)
{
  NSNumber *num1 = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
  for(int j = i + 1; j < arr.count; j++)
     {
       NSNumber *num2 = [arr objectAtIndex:j];
       //compare here num1 with num2
     }
 }
```

Comment: Not clear why this was down-voted, as it is essentially the same as Jsdodgers'.

Comment: yes I don't know, I was impressed and I revised my answer many times to discover why they vote down me!!!